# After cash on delivery redirect a page in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.1, cash-on-delivery

**I want to redirect set Cash On Delivery Payment method so how can it be done?**

> Means After cash on delivery redirect a page in Magento 2

Comment: it when a customer select on  cash on delivery method and after that  when click `place order` button it will redirect to your custom page?

Answer (score 0):

in your events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="neo_ordercomment_observer_orderneo" instance="Neo\OrderComment\Observer\Orderneo" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Here is my events.xml

And my observer file is Orderneo file,

> namespace Neo\OrderComment\Observer;

```
class Orderneo implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(
            \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context 
     ){
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     if($order->getPaymentType()=='cashPayment')
     {
           $resultRedirect->setUrl('frontname/controller');
           return $resultRedirect;
     }
    }
}
```